# Installing QGIS on network drive

Tags: qgis, installation, network, windows

Is it possible to save the QGIS installater file (QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.28.9-1.msi) on a network drive so that several users who have mapped the server can open and use QGIS? I am having problems installing because the .msi freezes when I select the path. Would it be a better alternative to copy the already installed QGIS folder to the network? I am using Windows 10 .

Comment: what if you have the msi on a standard folder and install to the network folder

Comment: @nmtoken  I get the following error message from the installer when selecting the path: QGIS 3.28.9 'firenze' Setup "An Error occurred while attempting to create the directory: "W:/.../apps/Qt5" "

Comment: Do you have appropriate permissions to create folders in your networked folder location?

Comment: I can create folders manually without any issues. I cannot run the msi file with administrator permissions. It could be that the installer has no right to creathe folders on the server. Could you think of a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

We have done this before, however we advise the users to copy the installer into their computer then install on their machines. If you have 100 people installing at the same time it would congest the network as I know.

Comment: ok thanks for the quick respond. I would either like to 1) save my QGIS program (with all plugins and custom settings) to a new msi file to contribute my own version of the program or 2) install QGIS on the server (so you could launch project over the mapped network drive) but I get the following error message from the installer when selecting the path: QGIS 3.28.9 'firenze' Setup "An Error occurred while attempting to create the directory: "W:/.../apps/Qt5" "